# SQL Date only in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am drawing a blank on how to do this:

```
select * from InvoiceInfo
where InvoiceDateTime = '2015-07-01'
```

The Invoicedatetime column is datetime and I only want to compare against a date.  This is on MS SQL 2012

Comment: in your where you need CAST('2015-07-01' AS DATETIME)

Comment: There are several ways - some better than others:  1. Convert to `date`, 2. String comparison, 3. `>= '2015-07-01' AND < '2015-07-02'`

Comment: So using one of the methods in the linked answer, your `WHERE` looks like `WHERE cast(InvoiceDateTime as date) = '2015-07-01'`